# issue in loading subset of data by getting value from the user in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue in the way I am doing pagination. suppose I have 10 pages and when user click on the page number it loads the data correctly but I have issue in clicking next and previous.

I have this html file:

```
 <% for(var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){ %>
            <% if(i === 0){ %>
                <li><a class="a-page-item current" >Previous</a></li>
                <li class="a-page-item current" ><%= i+1 %></a></li>
            <% } else if(i > 0 && i < 10 - 1){ %>
                <li><a class="a-page-item current"> <%= i+1%> </a></li>
            <% } %>
        <% } %>

    <li class="arrow"><a class="a-page-item current" >Next</a></li>
```

my problem is that when I click next I want the current page to be added by 1. but I do not know how to take care of "Next" which is a string. I need to keep current page somewhere and then when I click Next it adds 1 to current page. thats what I tried, but I recieves the error, because it wants to load "Next" which is the string not currentpage +1!

```
onPageClick : function(event) {

                var currentPage = event.target.innerHTML;
                if (currentPage == "Next"){

                    var currentPageInt = parseInt(currentPage);
                    this.currentPageInt +1;
                    this.setPagination(currentPageInt, 10);
                }


                else if (currentPage == "previous"){

                    var currentPageInt = parseInt(currentPage);
                    this.currentPageInt - 1;
                    this.setPagination(currentPageInt, 10);

                }

                else {
                var currentPageInt = parseInt(currentPage);
                this.setPagination(currentPageInt, 10);

            }

            },
```

by the way `this. setPagination(currentPageInt, 10);` loads 10 data from the page that user selects.

Comment: Close-voters/down-voters: I rolled back the most recent edit.  It appeared to be an error.

Answer (score 0):

How's this?

```
onPageClick : function(event) {
  var currentPage = event.target.innerHTML;
  if (currentPage === "Next") {
    this.currentPageInt++;
  } else if (currentPage === "Previous") {
    this.currentPageInt--;
  } else {
    this.currentPageInt = parseInt(currentPage);
  }
  this.setPagination(this.currentPageInt, 10);
},
```

Comment: thanks but I need my current page to be changed when ever user click on page number. so when I click on Next the current page would be equal to "Next" and I cannot do this.currentPage++; because current page is now a string. what I want is to keep the current page in a variable seprately and when I click next that variable added to 1. but I do not know how to do that. because when I write var keep = this.currentpage I cannot use it inside next and previouse because it is not defined

Comment: @user2781855, how about my amended answer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've already noticed that, but you are trying to parse "Next" and "previous", which results in `NaN` (Not A Number) :

```
if currentPage == 'Next'
    parseInt('Next') // NaN
if currentPage == 'previous'
    parseInt('previous') // NaN
```

Also be careful with "previous", the actual inner HTML is "Previous" :

```
"previous" == "Previous" // false
```

To prevent this kind of error to repeat later, you may use the class attribute. This will allow you to change the inner HTML with no need to update the javascript part :

```
<a class="next">Next page</a>
<a class="previous">Previous page</a>
if jQuery(e.target).hasClass('next')
    // increment
if jQuery(e.target).hasClass('previous')
    // decrement
```

Another point is that you currently don't save the incremented value :

```
this.currentPageInt = 1;
this.currentPageInt + 1; // 2
this.currentPageInt; // still 1
```

Here are various ways to solve this problem (same for `-`) :

```
this.currentPageInt = this.currentPageInt + 1;
this.currentPageInt; // 2
this.currentPageInt += 1;
this.currentPageInt; // 3
this.currentPageInt++;
this.currentPageInt; // 4
```

That said, `var currentPageInt` is useless, you should remove it completely and use `this.currentPageInt` instead. But more importantly, parsing only in the third case (when the user clicks on a page number) may solve your problem.